# How to compare content of one file to the another file in shell script line by line?

Tags: bash, shell-script

**File 1 Content(TOp.txt) :**

```
/
/boot
/home
/ptd
/ptd/tcd
/ptd/splunkforwarderdd
/ptd/sdt/pqr
/ptd/smr
/ptd/apps/ddas
```

**File 2 Content(POp.txt) :**

```
/
/boot
/home
/ptd
/ptd/tcd
/ptd/apps/ddas
/ptc/ddd
```

**Output File 1(Op1.txt) :**

```
/ptd/splunkforwarderdd
/ptd/sdt/pqr
/ptd/smr
```

**Output File 2(Op2.txt) :**

```
/ptc/ddd
```

```
while read linesT; do
TOp=$linesT
while read linesP; do
    POp=$linesp
    if [[ "$TOp" == "$POp"  ]]; then        
       a=cool
    else 
       echo $TOp
    fi
  done < POp.txt
done < TOp.txt
```

I tried the above code, but Its not working as expected.

I want `TOp.txt` file compare every line with every line in `POp.txt` file and show missing lines from file `TOp.txt` as output.

Same for `POp.txt` file.

Comment: Does it have to be a command-line tool? Otherwise, `meld` is a great graphical tool for file comparisons.

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will be assuming that we can treat the two files as text files containing lines, i.e., that none of the pathnames in the files have embedded literal newlines, and if they have embedded newlines, these are encoded somehow (possibly as `\n`).  With this assumption, we may use `comm` on the sorted data to extract the pathnames unique to each file.  Sorting the data is a requirement for using `comm`.

Only lines that are unique to the first file:

```bsh
comm -23 <( sort TOp.txt ) <( sort POp.txt ) >Op1.txt
```

If any or both of the files are already sorted, you may obviously use these files as-is without the `<( sort ... )` process substitution.

Only lines that are unique to the second file:

```bsh
comm -13 <( sort TOp.txt ) <( sort POp.txt ) >Op2.txt
```

By default, `comm` outputs three columns:

1. the lines unique to the first file,
2. the lines unique to the second file, and
3. the lines found in both files.

You "turn off" the columns using `-n` where `n` is the number 1, 2, or 3.  For example, in the first command above, we use `-23`, which is the same as `-2 -3`, which turns off all but the first column of the default output.

Comment: Can you try for the above data.

Comment: It is not working as expected.

Comment: @Shr In what way is it not working as expected?

Comment: Can you please check for above data. I have edited the content.

Comment: @Shr Yes, I checked already. What is the issue? I get the same lines as output as you mention in the question. Consider helping me by telling me exactly what is wrong so that I most effectively can help you with your issue.

Comment: Its working now, file must be in unsorted form.